# Overriding Firefox 11's baked-in css

Tags: css, firefox, css-reset

I'm trying to remove the 8px margin from the body tag.

I've tried (not all at once)

```
 * { padding:0; margin:0; }
```

and

```
 html, body { padding:0; margin:0 !important; }
```

and

```
 body { margin:-8px; }
```

and even

```
 <body style="margin:0">
```

The last one works, but only if I add the style attrib using Firebug; if it's in the original HTML, it gets ignored.

I'm at my wit's end.

Edit: *facepalm* I figured it out; I'd changed it to a cfm so I could easily call browser-specific styles. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: When checking in FireBug, can you see any other styles being applied? It may be overridden

Comment: The only margin listed on the body tag comes from FF's stylesheet; the one I added doesn't show.

Comment: @zzjoanw - That's interesting. Your stylesheet probably isnt linked right. Include your HTML for linking your stylesheet in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a reset stylesheet instead, this way you will reset all of the default values equally in all browsers.

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Since I'm (currently) only interested in the body margin, how is that going to work better than what I've done?

Comment: You have already exhausted all tries of removing the margin from the body tag, including using the `!important` rule and still nothing, maybe its another tag which is causing the margin and not the body tag? With a reset sheet you will target all of the elements in one go and so it might work. Otherwise you will need to post a test site so we can take a look, because all you're going to get are guesses.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is:

```
body { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

The `padding` is not needed for Firefox, but for Opera, which uses padding instead of margin for the default.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k3j8Y/

Answer (score 0):

```
body{ margin: 0;}
```

works ok for me :P

Answer (score 0):

**Include your stylesheet correctly**

As your style is not appearing in FireBug's CSS rule stack, your CSS is probably not linked correctly. Ensure the stylesheet is in your head tag like so:

```
<head>
    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
```